QuestPDF почему документ становится пустым после добавления таблицы и как это исправить?
// Создание PDF-документа в отдельном потоке
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Document.Create(document =>
    {
        document.Page(page =>
        {
            page.Size(PageSizes.A4);
            page.Margin(2, Unit.Centimetre);
            page.PageColor(Colors.White);

            page.Content().Column(column =>
            {
                // Разыменование вероятной пустой ссылки.
                column.Item().Text($"АКТ №{orderWithCustomer.Order.Id} от {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")} г.")
                             .Bold()
                             .FontSize(14)
                             .FontFamily("Courier New")
                             .Underline();
                // Разыменование вероятной пустой ссылки.

                column.Item().Text($"Заказчик: {orderWithCustomer.Customer.CompanyName} ИНН {orderWithCustomer.Customer.Inn}")
                             .FontSize(10)
                             .FontFamily("Trebuchet MS");

                column.Item().Text($"Юр. адрес:")
                             .FontSize(10)
                             .FontFamily("Trebuchet MS");

                column.Item().Text($"Исполнитель: ИП Сухин Владимир Анатольевич; ИНН: 575200444890\r\nЮр. адрес: 302531, обл. Орловская, р-н Орловский, д. Кондырева, ул Мира, д. 36.\r\nОснование: ДОГОВОР - ЗАЯВКА № 21522777 на осуществление перевозки груза от 12.01.2024\r\nВодитель- Сухин В.А.\r\n")
                             .FontSize(10)
                             .FontFamily("Trebuchet MS");
                column.Spacing(20);


                column.Item().Table(table =>
                {
                    table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.ConstantColumn(50); // № 
                        columns.ConstantColumn(200); // Наименование услуг, работ
                        columns.ConstantColumn(80); // Кол-во
                        columns.ConstantColumn(50); // Ед.
                        columns.ConstantColumn(100); // Цена
                        columns.ConstantColumn(100); // Сумма
                    });

                    table.Header(header =>
                    {
                        header.Cell().Text("№");
                        header.Cell().Text("Наименование услуг, работ");
                        header.Cell().Text("Кол-во");
                        header.Cell().Text("Ед.");
                        header.Cell().Text("Цена");
                        header.Cell().Text("Сумма");
                    });

                    table.Cell().Text("1.");
                    table.Cell().Text("Транспортные услуги по маршруту:\nЕкатеринбург -Секиотово, Октябрьское");
                    table.Cell().Text("1");
                    table.Cell().Text("-");
                    table.Cell().Text("35 000,00");
                    table.Cell().Text("35 000,00");
                });


            });
            
        });
    }).ShowInPreviewer();
});


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

У меня есть пдф файл, который я формирую при помощи кода, я пытаюсь в него добавить таблицу, которая содержится в column.Item().Table, но при добавлении этого элемента пдф файл становиться пустым, как мне правильно добавить таблицу
